# Shell Percentage Calculation With Very Large Numbers

Tags: shell

I've created a shell script to work out the percentage used on a hard drive.

Problems occur because some of the drives are very small, and some are very large. Also some of the very large drives return '0' percent when rounded and I would like it to return 0% instead of returning nothing.

Here is my code- which is quite messy, $MAX is the total size and $RESULT is the size used.

I've had to stick in the 'if' statement to bring the very large numbers down to a size that the percentage calculation can process. Then it cuts off everything after the decimal point so it returns a reasonable result.

```
if [ $MAX -gt 100000000 ]
    then
        MAX=$((MAX/100000))
        RESULT=$((RESULT/100000))
fi

RESULT=$(echo "scale=8;100/$MAX*$RESULT" | bc | cut -d. -f1)
```

Examples of the entries are-

MAX = 725632510
RESULT = 3309452

This returns 0, is there a way of getting this to actually return 0 instead of returning nothing? All in all it all seems like a very messy way of doing something that should be quite simple, so any other solutions are welcome!

Comment: If you don't want the fractional part, why don't you use `scale=0`? or do the arithmetic in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` to fix your number:

```
RESULT=$(printf "%.0f" $(echo "scale=8;100/$MAX*$RESULT" | bc))
```